# How can I stop floating the number keypad on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad, android-input-method, android-inputtype

The Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 (*SM-T235*) with Android 4.4.2 displays per default the floating numeric "Samsung-Keyboard" for all numeric inputs (*android:inputType="number"*). For all other inputs (e.g *android:inputType="text"*) it displays the "normal" docked (non floating) keyboard.

The main problem is that the floating keyboard overlays may other input fields and buttons so that the user has to move the keyboard around in order to see the whole form. How can I stop it from floating and set it as docked?

I found a similar question here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73487/how-do-i-stop-floating-the-number-keypad-on-galaxy-note-8-0

Comment: Oh, finally, someone like me! This is a really good question and I want to thank you for asking. I have the same problem on my Android tablet.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround. Turning on the magnification gestures, the floating numeric keyboard will be automatically disabled. It is not the best solution but it works for me.
Here is description on how to enable it: http://inside-galaxy.blogspot.ch/2014/03/samsung-galaxy-s4-how-to-fix-cant-find.html